# AngularFire2 document snapshotChanges returns undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I created router guard that first get id of authenticated user and then values based on user id from firestore, but when i log data returned from firestore its undefined (exists: false). Here is my code

**project.guard.ts**

```
export class ProjectGuard implements CanActivate {

item: Observable<any>;

constructor(
  private auth: AuthService,
  private afs: AngularFirestore,
) { }
canActivate(
  next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

this.item = this.afs.collection("project").doc(next.paramMap.get('pid')).snapshotChanges();

return this.auth.user.pipe(take(1), switchMap(u => {
  return this.item.pipe(
    take(1),
    map(data => {
      console.log(data)
      console.log("Hello: " + u.uid + " data: " + data.payload.doc.data());
      return true;
    }),
  );
})
)}
```

I am getting this error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

[image]

Do you have any idea why its undefined? When I try promise it works...

**promise**

```
this.afs.collection("project").doc(next.paramMap.get('pid')).ref.get()
```

But with `snapshotChanges()` or `valueChanges()` it's not working. I also tried just simple not nested pipe. Do you have any idea? Thank you

Comment: Did you enable offline capabilities in your project ?

Comment: No I didn’t, I think it’s not a good idea for this app

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call `data.payload.doc.data()` but if you look at the output from `console.log(data)` you'll see that it doesn't contain any `data.payload.doc` property.

There's `data.payload` but no `data.payload.doc`.